# AccessibilityLabel not work as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, accessibility

I want to support `VoiceOver` in my App but i have a few Problems. I have a `UITableView` with some cells, to support `VoiceOver` I do the following:

```
cell.labelMorning.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText;
cell.labelAfternoon.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText;

//Without VoiceOver
cell.labelMorning.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", model.startTimeM, model.endTimeM];
cell.labelAfternoon.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", model.startTimeA, model.endTimeA];

//When VoiceOver is activated
cell.labelMorning.accessibilityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@ %@  to %@ a Clock ",model.startTimeM,model.endTimeM];
cell.labelAfternoon.accessibilityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ to %@ a Clock",model.startTimeA,model.endTimeA];
```

But when i activate VoiceOver, each Label get read twice, whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the trick is not to use `accessibilityLabel` but instead I use `accessibilityValue`!!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting the accessibility label right after setting the text of the label?

You set the accessibilityTrait already so VoiceOver knows to just read whatever the text for that label is. So by setting the text:

```
cell.labelMorning.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", model.startTimeM, model.endTimeM];
```

You are already setting the accessibilityLabel too. I'm not sure if this is your source code but you might want to add an if statement to [check if VoiceOver is running](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1615187-uiaccessibilityisvoiceoverrunnin?language=objc) and then make the text include 'to' instead of '-' if it is.